# OMNET++ makefile:97 out/clang-release error

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, release, omnet++

During running this git: https://github.com/T-amairi/IOTA?tab=readme-ov-file on OMNET++ IDE I've got this errors:

```
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:/Users/MICRO/Downloads/Programs/omnetpp-6.0.2/samples/IOTA-main/README.md.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\MICRO\Downloads\Programs\omnetpp-6.0.2\samples\IOTA-main"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

```
Creating executable: out/clang-release//IOTA-main.exe
lld: error: unable to find library -lomp
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:97: out/clang-release//IOTA-main.exe] Error 1
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

And this is the line 97 from the Makefile:

```
$(Q)$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $O/$(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(EXTRA_OBJS) $(AS_NEEDED_OFF) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_ON) $(LIBS) $(WHOLE_ARCHIVE_OFF) $(OMNETPP_LIBS)
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: Please edit your question and use code block formatting for the errors and makefile, so they are readable.

Comment: Is `Description Resource Path Location Type` the first thing printed?  The error message you see from make is not the actual error.  It's just make telling you that the command it invoked, which is the one at line 97, failed.  So your compiler exited with an error code.  Make has no idea why that happened: make is not a compiler.  Make assumes that your compiler will have printed some useful error messages you can use to figure out and fix the problem.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks I got what you said. I have edited the errors to the first thing printed. Please take a look and tell me what the problem could be.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the omp library, which is presumably the library for OpenMP.  You'll have to install it on your system.

Comment: @MadScientist OpenMP is already installed with the MinGW compiler

Comment: That may be so, but it's not installed in a way that allows linking.  I don't do Windows so I can't really help and this is not a makefile problem.  On GNU/Linux systems you often have to install a separate "dev" package if you want to compile against a library, rather than simply running already-compiled programs.  I don't know if that's true with whatever facility you're using.  Or maybe there's some other problem finding the library.